# Problema ao recuperar Dados null para um DataTable em C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, data, datatable

Estou trabalhando com C# e o Banco de Dados PostGreSQL, tenho um campo do tipo Date onde ele pode ser preenchido dd/mm/aaaa ou vazio null. o mesmo problema é referente a qualquer campo da tabela, se ela estiver vazia, mesmo podendo estar, ocorre o erro.

Quando faço então um select para recuperar todos os dados e atribuir a um DataTable ocorre o seguinte erro

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.ConstraintException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Falha ao ativar restrições. Uma ou mais linhas contêm valores que violam as restrições non-null, unique ou foreign-key.
```

Método Utilizado

```
public DataTable RetornaDT(string sSQL)
{
    DataTable dtDados = new DataTable();
    if (ConectaBanco())
    {
        _comando.CommandText = sSQL;
        dtDados.Load(_comando.ExecuteReader());
        DesconectaBanco();
    }
       return dtDados;
 }
```

Onde tenho a seguinte tabela correspondente no banco de dados

```
CREATE TABLE conta
(
  con_codigo serial NOT NULL,
  con_descricao character varying(60),
  con_valordaconta real,
  con_valoraserpago real,
  con_valorjapago real,
  con_formapagamento character varying(2),
  con_dinheiroouporc character varying(2),
  con_desconto real,
  con_juros real,
  con_jurosam real,
  con_multaporatraso real,
  con_datalancamento date,
  con_datavencimento date,
  con_datapagamento date,
  CONSTRAINT contas_pkey PRIMARY KEY (con_codigo)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE conta
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Qual o SQL usado pra criar a tabela em questão? Tem certeza que não colocou nenhum índice no campo ou colocou ele como not null?

Comment: O erro diz que foi violado a restrição não nula de uma foreing key, acho que seria interessante postar as classes envolvidas.

Comment: Não coloquei, porque quando eu salvo o con_datapagamento com null, porque ainda não ocorreu o pagamento ele consegue salvar normalmente, na minha visão o problema é a restrição não nula ao carregar para o DataTable, e com relação a classes, eu apenas instacio um DataTable, e apenas faço DataTable.Load realizando um execute Reader para posteriormente poder usar isso em um DataGrid

Comment: O erro não consiste apenas a Date mas sim qualquer campo que esteja vazio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema consiste na versão utilizada do npgsql, a versão 3.2 requer que os dados não estejam nulos ou vazio, bom não sei porque isso ocorre, mas ao voltar para uma versão anterior do npgsql eu consegui resolver o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Depende da versão utilizada no Npgsql pode ocorre esse erro, uma maneira de resolver isso é tratar esse no seu sql, ao inves de você mandar o campo como null você pode altera-lo e mandar em branco.

```
CASE WHEN DateColuna IS NULL THEN '' ELSE to_char(DateColuna, 'dd/mm/yyyy') END As Data
```

Comment: Isso até resolve o problema, porém não tem outro metodo para resolver o erro pelo proprio DataTable?

Comment: O erro não consiste apenas a Date mas sim qualquer campo que esteja vazio